# Launching neo4j in browser localhost:7474

Tags: neo4j

Hi I have been working on neo4j and when I restarted it I cannot view it anymore on the localhost... I used neo4j start from bin to launch it. I am getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. I have disabled the firewall but all is in vain. Any idea what can be wrong? I am using Windows 10. I also just noticed that when I put the command neo4j start it runs for a minute or two and just stops when I check neo4j status

Comment: Can you create a pastebin with neo4j.log file output ?
Also have you edited neo4j.conf file? And have you tried to restart your machine?

Comment: @Martha Are you saying that checking the server status causes the server to stop?

Answer (score 0):

Use neo4j console instead of neo4j start and post the error when it stops.

It is highly possible that you have made some changes to your neo4j.conf file or added few plugins(libraries) in plugins directory